# Footer appears in the middle of the page in IE only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I use this style information to make my footer stick to the bottom of my web pages and it works super in FF, Chrome and Opera. Only in IE, the footer appears in the middle of the page instead of at the bottom.

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; font-family: Georgia; }

#parent 
{
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#header { position: relative; left:0px; top:0px; width: 100%; height:45px; background-color: black; }

#content { padding-bottom: 150px; position: relative; }

#footer { position: absolute; left: 0px; width:100%; bottom: 0; height:80px; background-color: black; }
```

The HTML structure is as follows:

- HTML body tag

  - parent

    - header
    - content
    - footer

**Update**

I figured if I add a conditional this selector for IE, it works in both browsers.

```
#parent { height: 100%; /* min-height: 100%; */ }
```

Now, would someone please tell me if it is legal to add a conditional CSS comment in a .css file that is included as an external  in an HTML file? I guess not. How do I go about using this conditional comment without using an additional IE only CSS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}
```

Take a look in the source code and try it on any browser: [Footer at the bottom of the page](http://www.massive.lt/footer/). It works on IE7, IE8 and IE9, only IE6 and under will not becouse of min-height property. I think putting correct DOCTYPE will fix your issue. Hope that helped.

Comment: Take a look in the source code and try it on any browser: [Footer at the bottom of the page](http://www.massive.lt/footer/). It works on IE7, IE8 and IE9, only IE6 and under will not becouse of min-height property. I think putting correct DOCTYPE will fix your issue.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Wow! You're the man! It worked like a charm. Putting the DOCTYPE worked. Yay! You're just awesome. And you're very kind. You put up that whole webpage just for me. Wow! Thanks much.

Comment: Just out of curiosity what server side technology did you use on that domain? I can see it has a url routing mvc based framework like rails or asp.net mvc.

Comment: I need a minimum reputation of 15 to vote your answer up. Will do that as soon as I get the minimum reputation. Thanks again.

Comment: That's just a simple HTML page, no frameworks. I've just created a folder named "footer" and uploaded this file. It took about 2 minutes to make, so no big deal.

I'm glad I've helped.

Comment: Oh, I could've guessed that. Thanks anyway. Am just looking, though, some of the pages are all screwed up now. I put up a Transitional loose.dtd DOCTYPE. Some pages where I have absolute positioned elements now have the footer sticking upwards in the middle of the page.

Comment: Well I expected that. Try using HTML4 DOCTYPE: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a few weeks back and a found a pretty good tutorial on this. [Click here!](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) The general idea behind this solution is to create a wrapper which soaks up most of the page, leaving only enough room for your footer to be positioned at the bottom of the page. This trick definitely works in IE.

Comment: What I have is roughly the same structure, if you pay close attention. The wrapper you mention is my #content div.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. It's a huge investment to change the structure of all the pages of a website. However, if nothing else works, I will certainly try this one out fully. At the moment, I have two options: one is to use a conditional comment in the CSS to simply tell IE to use a different style sheet. Another is to see if the correct DOCTYPE declaration on every page will eliminate my problem.